# He "left" a comment on website this morning vs "had left"

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

I'm confusing the past simple and the past perfect, particularly in following case; I don't know which one do I have to use.

> Ms. Koo, one of our regular customers, (left / had left) a question regarding the usage of the new vacuum cleaner on our website this morning.

Could you guys explain which one is correct and why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Using the past tense would be more proper, although both can work.

> Ms. Koo. one of our regular customers, left a question
>   regarding the usage of the new vacuum cleaner on our website this
>   morning.

*Past perfect tense* must be used when you are talking about two actions that happened in the past, one after the other, see:

> **Yesterday**, I checked the company email and saw that Ms.Koo, one of our
>   regular customers, **had left** a question regarding the usage of the new
>   vacuum cleaner on our website this morning.

As  you can see, I was talking about an action in the past. I mentioned two actions in the past, so "had" proceeded right before the other action in the past.

See other examples:

- I lost so much weight because I had begun exercising.
- He stayed up all night because he had received a lot of homework.
- I had met him before you introduced us.

[Examples of Past Perfect - really-learn-english.com](http://www.really-learn-english.com/examples-of-past-perfect-tense.html)

Comment: "must be used (when you are talking about two actions that happened in the past, one after the other)"? No, I don't think so.

Comment: @Damkerng T.
It doesn't necessarily need to follow this order, but it must be two actions that happened in the past, but not necessarily in that order. Do you think it might get the OP confused, should I cut this part out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to say. Is it "It doesn't necessarily need to follow this order (that it [the past perfect] must be used, but if it's so it must be used) ...", or "It doesn't necessarily need to follow this order (as in you don't need to use the past perfect if one action happened after another) ..."? In any case, do you think a sentence/utterance such as *He met her before I did* is incorrect because it doesn't use the past perfect?

Comment: @Damkerng T. Like: It doesn't have to be two things that happened one after other, you can specific two differents actions in the past, but in order to use the past perfect, you need to specify two actions that both happened in the past. Both _He met her before I did it_ or _He had met her before I did it_ are correct, although it is rare to find past perfect tenses used before verb to be. But it works fine too

Comment: So you disagree with this part in your answer, "Past perfect tense must be used when you are talking about two actions that happened in the past, one after the other", I think, right?

Comment: @Damkerng T. Your sentence is placed in the past tense, you just didn't mention when you did such thing, but it could have been written this way: He had met her before I did  homework yesterday. Or: Yesterday, I had done my homework before he met her.

Comment: @Damkerng T. - In few cases, your statement could be placed both in past perfect tense: _I had met her before he had done his homework_: this one implies to mean that I met her first, and he did his homework after I met her. 

_I had done my homework before he had met her_: this one implies to mean the same as above, but I did my homework before he met her.

Comment: More support for the answer: http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/.  More complete discussion: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html

Answer (score -3):

My explanation might not be that clear but I will try to provide an explanation for the past simple: it is used in the situation that happened once in the past and has already ended.

So

> He left a comment

I think should be more proper, as the previous answer says.